# Formatting/Indenting JaxB marshaller in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jaxb

I'm trying to PrettyPrint/indent/format the output XML from the Jaxb2Marshaller class in Spring, and even though I'm entering the property as seen elsewhere on the web, the file is still all on one line. Here's my bean declaration:

```
<bean id="pingerMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            ...
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="marshallerProperties">
        <map>
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <util:constant static-field="javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT" />
                </key>
                <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And the writer:

```
<bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="pingerMarshaller" />
    <property name="overwriteOutput" value="true" />
    <property name="resource" value="file:\C:\source\pinger\pingerExample.xml" />
</bean>
```

Am I missing something, or is this a bug?

Comment: That seems right. Are you sure Spring is using your marshaller and not some default one?

Comment: Added the writer to the question. Looks like I am using the correct marshaller.

Answer (score 4):

The `Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT` does not apply when marshalling to StAX's `XMLStreamWriter` and `XMLEventWriter` (which is what I'm assuming `org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter` means).  If you want JAXB to format the result you would need an `OutputStream` or `Writer` based target if they are available.

Comment: Interesting. Do you mind expounding on that a little bit? I'm using Spring Batch, and as far as I know the StaxEventItemWriter is the preferred method to marshal. Perhaps there's a way to enable pretty printing on a writer level. Thanks!

Comment: @Dave4988 - There isn't too much more info I can provide.  From my JAXB experience I just know that a JAXB impl won't format the output to an `XmlStreamWriter`/`XmlEventWriter` so your current config is unlikely to work as is.  Likely you will need to choose a different output type.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is quite old but even I was trying to figure out how to print the output when using the `JAXB/Moxy` `marshaling` and `unmarshaling` along with `XMLStreamWriter`  and `XMLEventWriter`.

I am posting the answer here so it can be useful to someone else in the future. Following methods can be used to pretty-print or beautify the `XML`.

If you are using the `XmlStreamWriter` then you can use the `IndentingXMLStreamWriter` to pretty-print the output like this:

```
private final XMLEventWriter xmlEventWriter = new IndentingXMLStreamWriter(XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(System.out));
```

This comes from the following `dependency` package:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>txw2</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

For `XMLEventWriter` you can use the `IndentingXMLEventWriter` like this:

```
private final XMLEventWriter xmlEventWriter = new IndentingXMLEventWriter(XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventWriter(System.out));
```

This comes from following dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.stax-utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax-utils</artifactId>
            <version>20070216</version>
        </dependency>
```