# StaxEventItemWriter ignores Jax2bMarshaller properties

Tags: java, spring-batch, stax

I have a simple itemwriter that looks as follows:

```
    return new StaxEventItemWriterBuilder<AddSubscriptionXml>()
            .version("1.0")
            .rootTagName("BePostSubscriptionDistribution")
            .name("optInSumoItemWriter")
            .rootElementAttributes(rootAttrs)
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(sumoSavePath + "/opt_ins_add.xml"))
            .marshaller(jaxb2Marshaller)
            .build();
```

My marshaller has the following properties:

```
@Bean
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(getMarshallerProps());
    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(AddSubscriptionXml.class, ModSubscriptionXml.class, DelSubscriptionXml.class);
    return marshaller;
}

private Map<String, String> getMarshallerProps() {
    return new HashMap<>(){{
        put(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, UTF_8.toString());
        put(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        put("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "<!DOCTYPE BePostSubscriptionDistribution SYSTEM \"..\\BePostSubscriptionDistribution.dtd\">");
    }};
}
```

Oddly, the marshaller properties get ignored altogether by StaxEventItemWriter.

Firstly, the output looks like crap, no indentation.
But more importantly, I'm missing the DocType line:

Result (formatted myself):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BePostSubscriptionDistribution TimeDateStamp="2021-08-26 13:03:44.761" identification="addSubscription">
    <AddMagazineSubscription>
        <SubscriptionNumber EditionCode="EDITION_CODE_1">id__19860702 064M81</SubscriptionNumber>
...
```

Desired:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE BePostSubscriptionDistribution SYSTEM "..\BePostSubscriptionDistribution.dtd">
...
```

Any idea how to fix this? Massive time waster for something that ought to be trivial.

Note: in debug modus, I see that the marshaller properties are properly set when passed to the ItemWriter.

Note: I opened a Github issue here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3982

Answer (score 0):

After skimming over the source code, I don't think there is an immediate solution to this. The marshaller isn't used to write the xml file headers at first sight, but only for writing the xml items under the root.
I'll try to check with the counterparty to see if omitting the doctype is acceptable for them.

If there is no other option, I'll download the StaxEventItemWriter to analyse how the output stream is written and add the required functionality. Although offering a backdoor backup api would be better from the perspective of future upgrades (imo).

For the indentation, I used the patch mentioned here which works well: [The XML output from the Spring Batch Jaxb2Marshaller - Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT is not working, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566545/the-xml-output-from-the-spring-batch-jaxb2marshaller-marshaller-jaxb-formatted)

Although it's not clear to me why indentation / pretty print is not added to spring batch StaxEventItemWriter immediately as option instead of using an external library. Indentation seems to be a base requirement for anyone working with XML and sending unformatted xml in 2021 sort of weird IMO. Admins have the reflex to look at files immediately (possibly through the terminal) in case things things don't go as expected.

As per comment by @Mahmoud Ben Hassine:

I can fix the docType issue by overriding methods `startDocument` and `endDocument` by providing a custom implementation.
This would break current api regarding the rootElement as well, but nothing that can't be fixed from the child class.

Comment: `it's not clear to me why indentation / pretty print is not added to spring batch StaxEventItemWriter immediately`: This is because the `StaxEventItemWriter` delegates the marshalling process to the `Marshaller` interface from Spring OXM. As far as the Spring Batch is concerned, the String returned by the Marshaller is opaque. Spring Batch only writes that string as is to the output writer.

Comment: It seems that pretty printing the output is not compatible with Stax (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1754#issuecomment-566285984 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/19320949/5019386) which is used by `StaxEventItemWriter`. The issue you created on Github is a duplicate of https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1754. That said, I agree with you that indenting the output should not be that hard.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Currently the indentation is not a blocking issue for me, the patch worked. Thanks for your input.

Comment: you are welcome. In that case, could you please add a comment on the issue you created by referring to the patch you used from the other issue? And for the doc type line you want to add, have tried to override `StaxEventItemWriter#startDocument`?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine It could be a fix, I didn't look very close yesterday. Based on what I see in the base class, the `startDocument` method takes care of the xml line (which isn't a problem), and also the root element. When overriding this method it would seem that I also need to override the `endDocument` method. This will work for me if I have access to all required objects from the child. May be useful to isolate these methods into smaller implementations; although if I'm the only one with this requirement, may not be all that useful.

Comment: The "smaller implementations" you are looking for are the `HeaderCallback` and `FooterCallback`. The line you want to add could probably be added in those callbacks. The startDocument/EndDocument methods are for having full control over the start/end of the xml document (including the xml declaration, namespaces, etc).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I need the doctype line to be in between the xml declaration and the root element. The code behind the headerCallback isn't all that clear to me on first sight. I thought this callback was used for adding a header within the root, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: `The code behind the headerCallback isn't all that clear to me on first sigh`: the header callback lets you add content between the root element name and child elements (so this is not what you are looking for). `I need the doctype line to be in between the xml declaration and the root element`. You can do that by orverridding startDocument/endDocument.